# The "Price" attribute value is empty. Set the attribute and try again. Error while creating Configurable Product in Magento 2

Tags: magento, migration, magento2, configurable-product

While creating a configurable product i m getting the following error:

The "Price" attribute value is empty. Set the attribute and try again.

I checked the log file but nothing is there.

Its migrated from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

[screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZqJy.png)

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Yes, but its not correct way. I changed the EAV attriibute  required value to 0.